# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in Algorithmic Trading

Tags: javascript, algorithmic-trading

For some reason everytime I run this code, I catch the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" error. I don't understand why. This is the code:

```
console.log("BUY");
exchange.marketBuy()
.then(res => {
console.log("Buy successful");
hasPosition = true
setTimeout(strategy, 1000)
})
.catch(console.error);
```

The marketBuy() function is

```
    marketBuy() {
    client.getLatestInformation()
    .then(response => {
      var price = response.result[0].last_price;
      client.placeActiveOrder({
       side: "Buy",
       symbol: "BTCUSD",
       order_type: "Market",
       qty: 20,
       time_in_force: "GoodTillCancel",
       take_profit: price * 1.5,
       stop_loss: price / 1.5})
      .then(response => console.log(response))

    })
```

I've tried

```
console.log("BUY");
exchange.marketBuy()
.then(res => {
hasPosition = true
setTimeout(strategy, 1000)
return Promise.resolve(console.log("Buy successful"));
})
.catch(console.error);
```

I can't seem to find the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. How to ask applies here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, debugging, or tutorial service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The marketbuy function needs to return a promise in order for you to call `marketbuy().then()`. Currently it returns nothing. You need to add a `return` keyword to the first line. `function marketBuy() { return client.getLatestInformation().then( …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of different issues. As others have already pointed out, you are not returning a promise from the `makeBuy()` method. But, it does not seem as easy as simply adding a `return` statement as suggested. This is because it appears you actually need to wait for the inner promise to resolve from `client.placeActiveOrder()` before setting `hasPosition` to true.

So you have two options (#2 is recommended):

1. move the code that must wait for the inner promise to resolve, to the `.then()` of the inner promise thus (this creates problems of its own with the `hasPosition` variable):

```
client.placeActiveOrder({
       side: "Buy",
       symbol: "BTCUSD",
       order_type: "Market",
       qty: 20,
       time_in_force: "GoodTillCancel",
       take_profit: price * 1.5,
       stop_loss: price / 1.5})
      .then(response => {
         console.log(response);
         console.log("Buy successful");
         hasPosition = true;
         setTimeout(strategy, 1000);
         });
```

2. Use async/await to make your code read like a work flow:

```
    async marketBuy() {
      const response = await client.getLatestInformation();
      const price = response.result[0].last_price;
      const order = await client.placeActiveOrder({
        side: "Buy",
        symbol: "BTCUSD",
        order_type: "Market",
        qty: 20,
        time_in_force: "GoodTillCancel",
        take_profit: price * 1.5,
        stop_loss: price / 1.5
      })
      return order;
    }
```

Choice two is recommended because it allows you to code the way you have expected things to work. Here is the calling code that will no longer throw an error:

```
    console.log("BUY");
    exchange.marketBuy()
      .then(res => { // res here is the order returned
        console.log("Buy successful");
        hasPosition = true
        setTimeout(strategy, 1000)
      })
      .catch(console.error);
```